# scala create equal/hashcode/tostring without case class

Tags: scala

In scala, I can create a case class that will make my class have a equal/hashcode/tostring based off the fields.  Because the code I am writing is using hibernate so I can not use a case class.  I was wondering if there is a way in scala to mark a class to get equal/hashcode/tostring like a case class would?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a library called [ScalaEquals](https://github.com/dicarlo2/ScalaEquals) for that.

(It relies on macros so it needs Scala 2.10.x.)